# How to access a field of struct being inside an enum in Rust?

Tags: rust

Here is code snippet, illustrating the problem:

```rust
pub enum Foo1 {
    Bar(Foo2)
}

pub enum Foo2 {
    Inner(Foo3)
}

pub struct Foo3 {
    pub val: i32
}

fn main() {
    let s2 = Foo1::Bar(Foo2::Inner(Foo3 { val: 5 }));
    // println!("{}", s2.); // I want to print val field of Foo3 struct
}
```

How to do it without pattern matching?

Comment: The answers in the duplicate pretty much sum up your options: `match`, `if let`, or potentially just `let` if your enums only have one variant like you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I would reach for `if let` when you're only interested in one match branch:

```rust
if let Foo1::Bar(Foo2::Inner(foo3)) = s2 {
    println!("{}", foo3.val);
}
```

Your case is unusual in that none of your enums have more than one element – the *if* would always be true, which would raise an "irrefutable_let_patterns" warning.

Rather than silencing this warning (for the particular statement), a direct let binding is enough:

```rust
let Foo1::Bar(Foo2::Inner(foo3)) = s2;
println!("{}", foo3.val);
```

Thanks, Sebastian Redl, for this tip!

Comment: Since the enums have only one branch and the pattern is irrefutable, you can use direct let binding without the if: `let Foo1::Bar(Foo2::Inner(Foo3 { val })); println("{}", val);`

Answer (score 0):

I found what was looking for. Field destruction is what I needed.

```rust
if let Foo1::Bar(Foo2::Inner(Foo3{val:x})) = s2 {
    println!("{}", x)
}
```